# Does Excessive consents clause hold up against consent requests in GDPR

Tags: gdpr

[GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/) states that one must record consent https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/consent/how-should-we-obtain-record-and-manage-consent/. Ok.Now let us say it takes 256 bytes to store information about the user.There are 1 million users. So if a user gives and widthwraws consent every second it will take - 1 million * 256 *86400 * 365 (~= 8073 terabytes or 8 petabytes) or 366 per year which is infeasable for any small business. Can excessive and manifestly unfound clause hold here https://www.technologylawdispatch.com/2020/06/data-cyber-security/responding-to-requests-the-ico-considers-manifestly-unfounded-and-excessive-requests/      .

Comment: The Art 12 GDPR concept of "manifestly unfounded or excessive" requests only applies to data subject requests, e.g. access or erasure. This does not affect your more general obligation to be able to demonstrate compliance, e.g. in Art 5(2) or Art 7.

Comment: What do you personally feel should be done in the above situation?

Comment: Would you consider answering this : https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57915/is-it-considered-sale-of-data-to-integrate-a-payments-processor

Comment: While the ICO guidance you cite recommends storing *records* of consent, the GDPR itself merely requires you to *demonstrate* that the data subject has consented (cf EDPB guidelines 5/2020 section 5.1). This could be performed via records, but sometimes also by showing that processing is technically prevented from being carried out without consent – in my opinion an adequate approach for handling cookie consent.  And as Dale M shows, even records would take up far less space than you calculate (I'd expect a steady state of <2GB when keeping consent records for 2 years).

Comment: Ok. I will be baning users if they give and widthwraws consent every second.

Comment: Well the simple answer seems (I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice) you can ban a user saying they violated your terms of service by trying to disrupt your server and not for sending cookie requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your premise is absurd

Your example is manifestly absurd. You say, “**a** user gives and withdraws consent every second” which is clearly stupid because a) a server based solution won’t refresh that quickly, b) your user has nothing better (like sleeping, eating etc.) to do for a year than do this c) who does this? Further, you then apply this to **every** user.

Let’s assume something reasonable: there are 7 billion people in the world, half of them don’t have internet access. Let’s assume you have a wildly successful service and you reach just over half of these or 2 billion and, on average, they opt in and out twice a year so you need 1 kilobyte each (per year) and you keep your data on every user (active or not) for an absurdly long 10 years. That’s 20 petabytes.

At about 0.5 p per Gigabyte per month (and someone storing this much data will get considerably better rates) this is only about £100,000 per month. And, of course, with 2 billion users you aren’t exactly a small business.

### It doesn’t matter if it’s hard or expensive to comply with the law

Complying with the law is a cost of doing business. If this cost makes your business unprofitable, close your business.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116062/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-does-excessive-consents-clause-hold-up-against-co).